# group by with "holes" in the middle

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following table:

```
create table #Track (id int identity, vehicle int, station varchar(50), pieces int, distance int)
insert into #Track (vehicle, station, pieces, distance)
values 
(1, 'A', 10, 0), (1, 'B', 10, 50), (1, 'C', 11, 23), (1, 'D', 11, 40), (1, 'E', 10, 5)
```

This is the result I need (notice the change in the pieces field between C and D):

```
vehicle station_from    station_to  pieces  distance_all
1            A             B          10      50
1            C             D          11      63
1            E             E          10       5
```

If I do this query:

```
select  A.vehicle,
        T1.station station_from,
        T2.station station_to,
        A.pieces,
        A.distance_all
from (
select  vehicle,
        min(id) min_id,
        max(id) max_id,
        pieces,
        sum(distance) distance_all
from    #Track
group
by      vehicle,
        pieces
) A join #Track T1 on A.min_id = T1.id
    join #Track T2 on A.max_id = T2.id
```

I have a wrong result (the distance_all is correct, but the station from and to aren't. It seems as the vehicle 1 was going from A to E AND then from C to D:

```
vehicle station_from    station_to  pieces  distance_all
1             A              E        10         55
1             C              D        11         63
```

How to achieve the required result without using a cursor (the tables are rather big, several millions of records)

Comment: you don't specify the logic for grouping.

Comment: To be honest here, I don't "get it."  What rules are used for arriving at your desired output?

Comment: A good question: *Copy-Paste* scenario, expected output, own attempt ... +1 from my side

Comment: I don't get it either. I see you combine records with the same `vehicle` and `pieces`. There happen to be only two records for any such combination in your example. So is this guaranteed to be the case? Is this how you find pairs? And how do you determine which `station` is `station_from` and which is `station_to`? All this looks wrong somehow, and I guess AakashM is right assuming that you have some record order in mind which isn't really given.

Comment: OK. I'll try to elaborate: We are transporting goods. Goods can be added and removed everywhere during the track. We have to define a report where we show exactly how the journey was made (ie. between FROM and TO stations they have transported x amount of goods for y distance. Of course there are other data as well but I'm looking for the logic

Comment: how do you know which station is "from" and which is "to"?

Comment: The order of the id defines it. Actually those are events coming every minute from the vehicle computers and I have to summarize the results. FROM is the first event of that particular vehicle (and for the order number, but I do not want to bother you with that) and TO is the last event for the same vehicle (and order number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do. Treating consecutive rows with the same pieces value for a vehicle as one group and getting the min and max of station, sum of distance for that group. Use `lag` to get the previous row's pieces value and reset the group (in a running sum) when it is different from the current row. Thereafter, it is just a grouping operation.

```
select distinct vehicle
,first_value(station) over(partition by vehicle,grp order by id) as station_from
,first_value(station) over(partition by vehicle,grp order by id desc) as station_to
,pieces
,sum(distance) over(partition by vehicle,grp) as distance_all
from (select t.* ,sum(case when prev_pieces=pieces then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by vehicle order by id) as grp
      from (select t.*,lag(pieces) over(partition by vehicle order by id) as prev_pieces
            from Track t
           ) t
     ) t
```

[**`Sample Demo`**](http://rextester.com/UOAMQ55780)

Comment: You cannot use min(station) and max(station) as stations are not in alphabetical order.. In fact ID gives the right order

Answer (score 2):

This is a variant of the "gaps and islands" problem.  In your case, you can solve it with a difference of row numbers:

```
select vehicle,
       max(case when seqnum_grp = 1 then station end) as station_from,
       max(case when seqnum_grp_desc = 1 then station end) as station_to,
       pieces,
       sum(pieces) as pieces_all
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by vehicle, pieces, (seqnum - seqnum_p) order by id) as seqnum_grp,
             row_number() over (partition by vehicle, pieces, (seqnum - seqnum_p) order by id desc) as seqnum_grp_desc
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by vehicle order by id) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by vehicle, pieces order by id) as seqnum_p
           from #Track t
          ) t
     ) t
group by vehicle, pieces, (seqnum - seqnum_p);
```

To understand how this works, you need to understand why the difference in row numbers identifies the groups.  For that you need to just run the innermost subquery and stare at the results.

This is a bit trickier than most such problems because you want the first and last stations along the way.  Hence there is an extra subquery.

Comment: But there is an error for the station_to field as it gives twice the station_form station

Answer (score 1):

you can query as below:

```
Select vehicle, min(Station) as Station_From, Max(station) Station_To, pieces, sum(distance) as Distance_all 
from (
    Select *, [Bucket] =Row_number() over(order by id) - Row_number() over(partition by pieces order by id)
    from #Track
) a
group by vehicle, pieces, [Bucket]
```

Output:

```
+---------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------+
| vehicle | Station_From | Station_To | pieces | Distance_all |
+---------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------+
|       1 | A            | B          |     10 |           50 |
|       1 | E            | E          |     10 |            5 |
|       1 | C            | D          |     11 |           63 |
+---------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------+
```

Comment: what if the stations are not in alphabetical order?

Comment: Then we require to use row_num based on the same partition with pieces and order by id and get min and max value corresponding to min and max value of row_num...

Comment: That will only move the question to:  What if the stations are not in id order?

Comment: The stations (actually the events) ARE in id order